# Arranging the fields of a structure into order

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

I am trying find away of ordering a polynomial in the form a structure so that the exponent fields are in ascending order. I don't want to use a built in sort function to do this.
for example the polynomial:

```
p = struct('exponent',{2,3,2,9},'coeff',{1,2,91,40})
```

represents the polynomial:
p = 1(x^2) + 2(x^3) + 91(x^2)+ 40(x^9)
I want to rearrange it so that it becomes (the exponents are now in ascending order)
p =  1(x^2) + 91(x^2) + 2(x^3) + 40(x^9)

my code to do this is:

```
function [ output ] = myMergepoly2( p )

h=1;
output(1,length(p))=struct('exponent',{},'coeff',{});
while (h<length(p))
    if p(1,h+1).exponent<p(1,h).exponent
        output(1,h).exponent = p(1,h+1).exponent;
        output(1,h).coeff = p(1,h+1).coeff;
        h=h+1;
    else
        output(1,h).exponent = p(1,h).exponent;
        output(1,h).coeff = p(1,h).coeff;
    end
end

end
```

However when I try to run this function MATLAB remote has 'busy' written out with no error message. I am unsure what is causing this and how to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the `else` section of the loop, you don't increment `h`, so it goes like this:

`h=1`  --> `if p(1,h+1).exponent<p(1,h).exponent` is false --> skip to else loop and set `output(1,1).exponent` --> `h=1` (while loop keeps going).

Using MATLAB inbuilt sort I'd just do something along the lines of:

```
exponent = [p.exponent];
coeff = [p.coeff];
[exponent idx] = sort(exponent); 
output.exponent = exponent;
output.coeff = coeff(idx);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line :

```
output(1,length(p))=struct('exponent',{},'coeff',{});
```

With this line :

```
output = struct('exponent',cell(1,length(p)),'coeff',cell(1,length(p)));
```

Also put this instead:

```
while (h<length(p))
    if p(1,h+1).exponent<p(1,h).exponent
        output(1,h).exponent = p(1,h+1).exponent;
        output(1,h).coeff = p(1,h+1).coeff;
    else
        output(1,h).exponent = p(1,h).exponent;
        output(1,h).coeff = p(1,h).coeff;
    end
    h=h+1;
end
```

However I'm still not getting the right output, I'm working on it.